# Is it wrong when people say "from this year" instead of "starting this year"?

Tags: grammar, american-english

For example, I will work from this year.

To me, it sounds a bit incorrect. Maybe it's best to say "from this year on" or "from this year onwards"? Maybe it's just better to say, "starting this year" instead of "from this year"?